# Убрать рамку при нажатии на элемент

Tags: html, css, html5

При нажатии на элемент, вокруг него пунктирная рамка, как её убрать? За это отвечает какое-то свойство CSS или это особенность браузера (Firefox)? [image]

Comment: `outline: none`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ оформите, пожалуйста, как ответ, отмечу его правильным. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта рамка отображает фокус ввода пользователя, плохо ее отключать - у тех у кого нет мышки и есть только клавиатура - не смогут определить где фокус ввода.

Но если очень хочется - Вам поможет css правило:

`outline:none;`

`